# Getting Errors when trying to Deserialize JSON object from API call in C#. (currency exchange)

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net, deserialization

My goal is to build an API that can load currency data from https://openexchangerates.org/ api into our SQLite database. I am able to get the JSON object formatted like this:

[image]

When i run the code below, it returns an errors. I am not sure how to resolve this. Just need to convert this JSON into a C# class without error.

Here's the custom C# object to mapped to JSON obj:

```
     public class ExchangeRate
    {
        public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
        public string License { get; set; }
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        public string Base { get; set; }
        public string Rates { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the api call where its returning the error:

public static async Task<List> GetLatest(string url)
{

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string results = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        List<ExchangeRate> ratesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExchangeRate>>(results);
        return ratesList;
    }
```

[image: error msg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example JSON is not a list, it's a single object, this is specified in the exception message

> ...because the type requires a JSON array

, otherwise it would have [ ] around it indicating an array (can be deserialized to list). Also, your model is flawed as Rates is not a string, but an object, and Timestamp is not a string but a long for the datetime as ticks. Change your model like so:

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    //decorate your properties since the json string uses lowercase
    [JsonProperty("disclaimer")]
    public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("license")]
    public string License { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("base")]
    public string Base { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("rates")]
    public Rates Rates { get; set; }
}

public class Rates 
{
    //create the properties for the Rates class
}
```

OR make the rates property a `Dictionary<string, decimal>`, **NOTE**: this could fail if any key is duplicated.

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    //decorate your properties since the json string uses lowercase
    [JsonProperty("disclaimer")]
    public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("license")]
    public string License { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public long Timestamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("base")]
    public string Base { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("rates")]
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Change your code to this:

```
ExchangeRate rate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExchangeRate>(results);
```

Comment: Thanks! the error is gone! However, i am only getting 1 row back. I was hoping to get the list of rates. Right now its just returning the top one. How can i get all of the rates into a list? If that makes sense

Comment: @BakariLewis It looks to me from your example, I can't see all of it as it's cut off in the picture, but "rates" appears to be an object which contains different "rate" properties, ie. AED, AFN, etc... You need to create these in the suggested Rates class I added in my example above. Then, it will deserialize all the "rates" into this one object. Please remember that curly braces is an object and square brackets are an array. Or you can use a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` for the Rates object.

Comment: thank you so much, you are correct! its working great!

Comment: @BakariLewis Glad to help. Have a good day.

Comment: sorry one last question, Would you happen to know how I can derive the values from the Dictionary? I am trying to grab the value of the Rates (dictionary) and assign to an object that will be saved to the database.

Comment: @BakariLewis How do you want to store them? Can you please provide an example of what you have in mind? This will help me to help you.

Comment: so this is working. I stored them in a list. Is this a good way to do it? Or would you advise another way.

Comment: List<string> keys = rate.Rates.Keys.ToList();
 List<decimal> values = rate.Rates.Values.ToList();

Comment: @BakariLewis I see you want to store them in the database, but if you remove the keys, how will you know which value relates to which key when getting it from the database? How are you storing this in the DB, are you wanting to store it as a json string?

Answer (score 1):

Your C# class model does not match the incoming JSON data structure. Rates is an array of items, but you're treating it like a string in your C# model. Timestamp is a number but you're treating it like a string in your C# model.

```
public class ExchangeRate
{
    public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string License { get; set; }
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> Rates { get; set; }
}
```